# ArrayFormula date vlookup -30days in first 30 rows of Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, vlookup

I am trying to use an array in Google Forms Response sheet for a time sheet. I want to have a rolling 30 day total for hours worked. The first 30 days is not able to lookup 30days prior.

```
={"Previous-Duty Hours 30D prior";ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP(($B2-30),$B2:$F,5, FALSE))}
```

The result is Error:

> Did not find value '43523' in VLOOKUP evaluation.

How do I ignore the first 30days?
I also want to array `=SUM(I2+H3)` but the first row `=F2`. How do I manage the first row?

[image]

Comment: pls, share a copy of your sheet

Comment: what is the easiest way share the sheet? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nl7dWZh0HGLsPbnUhmctZBCzDrFo5vADOjRmfvNrQM8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: copy paste link of your sheet here and enable view in sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- your formula should probably be:

  ```
  ={"Previous-Duty Hours 30D prior"; 
    ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP((B2:B-30), B2:F, 5, 0)))}
  ```

Comment: Thanks very much. Your formula works a treat. I am sorting on Column B. I will need to seek some assistance on filling down in column G and onwards as my mojo with formula's seems to have departed. Really appreciate your assistance.